# How to use an alternate version of Apache Ant on OS X without installing over existing version?

Tags: macos, command-line, ant

I've found a few guides that tell how to replace the default version of Apache Ant on OS X; however, I'd rather not do that. My team and I share a common version of Apache Ant and it is stored in a common path on our individual systems. Periodically, we review tools in that path and sometimes update them to use the latest. For example, we have Apache Ant in: [USERPROFILE]/Developer/Tools/Apache/Apache Ant/apache-ant-1.8.2 Should 1.8.3 become available and address some problem, we'd likely want to switch to using it.

How can we configure our systems so that we can easily switch to using a new version of Ant or even revert back to using prior versions. 99% of the time, we simply want to execute "ant" at the command-line and not have to enter the full path to a specific version. I'm guessing there is an ideal .bash_profile setup, but I'm not that familiar with such settings... just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

There are many, many ways to implement this.  Personally, I keep multiple versions of ant under `/opt/ant`:

```
% ls -l /opt/ant
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x   1 hdm  admin       16 18 Oct 19:01 ant@ -> apache-ant-1.8.1
drwxr-xr-x  17 hdm  admin      578 13 Dec  2006 apache-ant-1.7.0/
drwxr-xr-x  14 hdm  admin      476 27 Jun  2008 apache-ant-1.7.1/
drwxr-xr-x  14 hdm  admin      476 30 Apr  2010 apache-ant-1.8.1/
drwxr-xr-x  15 hdm  admin      510 19 Sep  2008 apache-ant-antunit-1.1/
```

You'll notice that I keep a symlink to the one I want to use as the default.  In my `.bash_profile` (`.zshrc`, actually), I have:

```
PATH=/opt/ant/ant/bin:$PATH
```

That way, I just get whichever ant the symlink points at.  And on machines where I don't have these copies of ant installed, I just get the default ant in `/usr/bin`.